# Grepping dynamic patterns to different files on Unix

Tags: unix, awk, grep, tail

I need to grep several patterns from a text file that is updated constantly by a process.

So I would do:

```
tail -f file1.txt | egrep --line-buffered 'pattern' | tee pattern.txt
```

My problem is that these patterns need to be taken dinamically from the file. I.e:

```
file1.txt:
2012-01-05 21:32:41    server1    some_text
2012-01-05 21:42:51    server1    some_text
2012-01-05 22:12:43    server2    some_text
2012-01-05 22:32:11    server3    some_text
2012-01-05 22:43:14    server3    some_text
2012-01-05 23:31:21    server2    some_text
2012-01-05 23:42:11    server1    some_text
```

Now I need to grep these lines to three separated files: server1.txt, server2.txt. server3.txt, but "server1", "server2" and "server3" are patterns for grep that need to be taken dinamically from file1.txt. If then a new row that includes "serverx" is added to file1.txt I need a serverx.txt file to be created and the ouput from file1.txt redirected to this new file.

I think I will need a combination of tail, grep, awk, but I'm not sure how to start.

Thanks in advance!

Fran.

Comment: Where to start? Perl, http://www.perl.org/ :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about:

```
tail -f file1|awk '/yourPattern/{print $0 >> $3".txt"}'
```

didn't test, but should work.

then this oneliner will create server{1,2,3 }.txt  3 files based on your example

Comment: Wow... that was quick! Thank you for sharing your knowledge with me!

Answer (score 2):

Continuously dispatch the input file to the "pattern" files:

```
tail -f file1.txt | 
while read date time server text
do
   echo "$date $time $server $text" | tee -a "$server".txt
done
```

Comment: @Francisco Is it what you want?

Comment: Thank you oHessling! I will give it a try. However Kent's oneliner works as I expected.

Answer (score 1):

If `tail -f` is not madatory, you can also do:

```
awk '{print $3}' file1.txt | 
  sort -u | 
  while read pattern
  do 
     egrep --line-buffered "$pattern" file1.txt | tee "$pattern".txt
  done
```